# Take a part of the filename and copy it into the file

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a (batch) solution to copy a part of the filename into the textfile. All of the files (thousands) are in one directory and the modified files should go to another directory (let's say c:\tmp ).

The files are called:

```
0001_Songtitle1.txt
0002_Songtitle2.txt
0003_Songtitle3.txt
```

The leading number is always 4 digits, ending with a `_`, whereas the Songtitle can have a different length. I want the number (the first four digits) to be copied into the first row of each file in the following format:

(for the first file) `SongID:0001`

(for the second file) `SongID:0002`

(for the third file) `SongID:0003`

Anybody an idea?

I tried this code:

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%~nI>"%TEMP%\FileName.tmp"
    echo/>>"%TEMP%\FileName.tmp"
    copy /B "%TEMP%\FileName.tmp" + "%%~I" "%%~I.tmp">nul
    del "%%~I"
    ren "%%~I.tmp" "%%~nxI"
)
del "%TEMP%\FileName.tmp" 2>nul
```

It sends the complete filename (without .txt) into the first line. But I struggle to extract just the first four digits.

Thanks,
Ralf

Comment: Please show some code with what you have already tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Put `for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%J in ("%%~nxI") do echo SongID:%%J` as first line within your existing `for` loop. I'm sure, you can figure out the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried to put it into the right place, but without any success. Would you be able to send me the complete code (my code with your add on implemented)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is where I meant it to be inserted:

```
@echo off
for %%I in (????_*.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%J in ("%%~nxI") do (
    >"temp.tmp" echo SongID:%%J
    >>"temp.tmp" echo/
    copy /B "temp.tmp" + "%%~I" "%%~I.tmp">nul
    move /y "%%~I.tmp" "%%~nxI" >nul
  )
)
del "temp.tmp" 2>nul
```

I took the freedom to change your code slightly for readability and minor improvements.

Comment: Perfect! Works great. Thank you, very much.